# add Custom Prerequisite or script to add in installer to detect it

Tags: windows, installation, installer, windows-installer

I have a wpf application which needs to be deployed at clients system.

It has access database as back-end

now at time of installation I need to check if the user has office installed in its system or i have t provide link for access database driver

also needs to verify that the system is 32 bit or 64 bit so that i can redirect the user to respective driver url

any ideas guys how it can be done, I have used installer setup and deployment project